# Cohort by Month and Location in SQL (SSMS)

Tags: sql, ssms

I am trying to get a monthly cohort analysis from our database by month from 01/01/2015 to 01/01/2016. It needs to display it by month, by location. Here is what I have so far:

```
Select playsite_id, count([member_guid]) members,sum(TotalVisits) visitdiff                     
FROM                       
(SELECT playsite_id, member_guid,                      
         sum(case when [date_id] < 20150401            
                     then 1 
                     else null     
                     end) as PreviousVisits,    
       sum(case when [date_id] between 20150401 and 20150501                
                     then 1 
                     else null     
                     end) as CohortVisits,      
    sum(case when [date_id] between 20150401 and 20160401                         
                     then 1 
                     else null     
                     end) as TotalVisits  w
   FROM [Guest_Visit_Fact]                       
   where visit_type in ('WALK-IN NEW','WALK-IN REPEAT')              
   group by playsite_id, [member_guid]) as innertable                      
where PreviousVisits is null and CohortVisits > 0      
group by playsite_id
```

This code is for just the month of April. We are wondering if there is a way to do it so we don't have to rewrite the code 12 times, one for each month. Maybe we're overthinking it, we've hit a wall. Here's what that code returns.
So it shows, between April 2015 and April 2016, how many first time visitors came, and how many of those returned.
Any help would be appreciated. We're close, yet far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query

```
DECLARE @MonthStart INT, @YearStart INT ,@YearEnd INT 
SET @MonthStart=4
SET @YearStart=2015
SET @YearEnd=2016
WHILE @MonthStart <= 12 -- condition of months
BEGIN 
Select playsite_id, count([member_guid]) members,sum(TotalVisits) visitdiff                     
FROM                       
(SELECT playsite_id, member_guid,                      
         sum(case when MONTH([date_id]) <@MonthStart  AND YEAR([date_id])=@YearStart        
                     then 1 
                     else null     
                     end) as PreviousVisits,    
       sum(case when MONTH([date_id]) between @MonthStart and @MonthStart+1 and YEAR([date_id])= @YearStart               
                     then 1 
                     else null     
                     end) as CohortVisits,      
    sum(case when YEAR([date_id]) between @YearStart and @YearEnd AND MONTH([date_id]) = @MonthStart                       
                     then 1 
                     else null     
                     end) as TotalVisits  W
   FROM [Guest_Visit_Fact]                       
   where visit_type in ('WALK-IN NEW','WALK-IN REPEAT')              
   group by playsite_id, [member_guid]) as innertable                      
where PreviousVisits is null and CohortVisits > 0      
group by playsite_id 
SET @MonthStart=@MonthStart+1 
END
GO
```

I hope you work

Comment: Thanks so much, it looks like this worked! All I had to do was remove the "WHILE" on line 5, it wouldn't let me execute with that. I appreciate your help!

Comment: excuse me forget the condition of the while, but I already edit it

Comment: I'm having a little trouble. The "visit difference" is outputting lower numbers than the "members." It should be the other way around. It's probably something with the third sum case that is giving the issue. Any ideas?